# Disable ColdFusion file-handling for one VirtualHost (Apache2)

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2, redmine, coldfusion

I would like to disable the ColdFusion-Server for just one virtualhost within my apache. This one virtualhost is a ruby on rails application (redmine).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy way. I created a *.htaccess* and insert the following line:

```
 SetHandler text/html
```

After restarting apache, all files within the folder will be handled as html-files and not rendered by coldfusion or php.

Answer (score 3):

You can come close to doing this by using the security sandbox, just disable all tags & datasources - CF will however continue to process cfm/cfml files and some tags, but everything exciting will not be accessible, however, if you really need to disable all CF handling, you will actually have to disable the server wide jrun AddHandler & re-configure each vhost to use cfm.

something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_jrun22.c>
   AddHandler jrun-handler .jsp .jws .cfm .cfml .cfc .cfr .cfswf
</IfModule>
```

in each of your vhost confs... double check this with Google - but I beleive this is how I did this before. - Also, the plesk CF plugin does exactly this - maybe take a peek at how they implement this.

-sean

Comment: Thanks, I will check this next week - i will accept this, if it works!

Answer (score 2):

It should not be necessary to disable ColdFusion for any host. As long as you do load any .cfm/.cfc files in the application, ColdFusion will not process anything and stay out of your way.

Comment: I want to access some .cfm files with redmine - and i want to see the diff of the latest versions. But the file is handled by coldfusion before redmine can show the diff. So "do not access cfm-files" is no solution for my problem.